# How to insert value with quotes in DataStage?

Tags: csv, etl, datastage, ibm-infosphere

Hello i've been having a problems because of the source file containing multiple double-quotes.

I've been trying to figure out how it is, and i'm currently using a regex in transformer stage

**This is the Source (csv)**

"Error--Setting Bp Auto Risk Classification Failed Log #216079 s#err.mba$org_struct.oe#predecessor_oe: i_oe..........................[63888] i_oe_type_id..................[6299] i_eff_date....................[18-APR-2019] i_oe_level....................[5]  /  ORA-20003: Severe Error on log (216078): ORA-21780: Maximum number of object durations exceeded. ORA-06512: at ""K.ERR#"""

**This is my Transformer**

```
Convert('"','', DSLink5.REMARK)
```

**Result i've got with regex**

Error--Setting Bp Auto Risk Classification Failed Log #216079 s#err.mba$org_struct.oe#predecessor_oe: i_oe..........................[63888] i_oe_type_id..................[6299] i_eff_date....................[18-APR-2019] i_oe_level....................[5]  /  ORA-20003: Severe Error on log (216078): ORA-21780: Maximum number of object durations exceeded. ORA-06512: at K.ERR#

**THE Result i wanted**

Error--Setting Bp Auto Risk Classification Failed Log #216079 s#err.mba$org_struct.oe#predecessor_oe: i_oe..........................[63888] i_oe_type_id..................[6299] i_eff_date....................[18-APR-2019] i_oe_level....................[5]  /  ORA-20003: Severe Error on log (216078): ORA-21780: Maximum number of object durations exceeded. ORA-06512: at "K.ERR#"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fortunately (lol) I'm able to answer my own problem by reading the documentations.

```
Trim(DSLink5.REMARK, '"', "R")
```

This is my solution. Thankyou for everyone trying to help !

Answer (score 0):

So a first try could be to replce "" with " right?

```
Convert('""','"', DSLink5.REMARK)
```

You might want to add more replace/convert options if you also got """ in your source

Comment: I wanted to trim the outer quote (")  and make the only quote available is on "K.ERR#" . 
Is that even possible? since i don't have the authorization to change the source file.